# Valid unprepared query not functioning in migrations

Tags: laravel

(Laravel 5.6)
I'm having issues executing DB::unprepared query in a laravel migration. The query is valid, as I can copy-paste it directly in my db management app. But within an unprepared query, nada. I'm not getting any errors whatsoever.

I've tried using DB::raw and a combination of the two, as seen in other posted questions, to no avail. Anybody spot any obvious errors that I'm missing? TIA.

```php
DB::unprepared(
    'Update protocols AS P
        INNER JOIN (
        SELECT auditable_id, updated_at
        FROM logs
        WHERE auditable_type = \'App\\Protocol\'
        AND event = \'updated_status\'
        AND new_values LIKE \'%pending irb specialist review%\'
        OR
        auditable_type = \'App\\Protocol\'
        AND event = \'updated_status\'
        AND new_values LIKE \'%pending faculty sponsor approval%\'
        )
        AS L ON L.auditable_id = P.id
    SET P.submitted_on = L.updated_at
    WHERE P.id = L.auditable_id'
);
```

Comment: *"I've tried using DB::raw and a combination of the two"* - In what order? The examples I'm seeing indicate that you need `DB::unprepared(DB::raw(...));`. My first thought is that this isn't actually executing a query. For example, using Eloquent, until you pass a closure, like `->get()`, or `->first()`, etc, the query isn't actually run. Edit: The documentation says `unprepared(string $query)`, so I guess this *should* work?

Comment: Yes, I've indeed tried the `DB::unprepared(DB::raw()); ` - No workie.

Comment: Yeah, and the documentation suggests as such. Now you say you're running this in a `migration`, is this in the `public function up()` of said migration?

Comment: yes, it's within up(). It has to do with the Inner Join, as I can remove that portion and update a datetime value to the protocols table as expected.

Comment: I ended up re-writing this as a select and running a foreach() to solve it. But I would still like to know _why_ this didn't work. Thanks all.